# angular ui-grid event: column selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to get selected column value based on the selection of a column on ui grid. From that value i used to filter another uigrid table so how to call a function on select of column and the selected column value.

This is my sample code which i am using presently:

```
$scope.gridOptions[0].onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
                $scope.gridApi.push(gridApi);
                gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(newRowCol, oldRowCol){

                    var name = newRowCol.col.name;

                    var  filterWithData = newRowCol.row.entity[name];
                    //$scope.filtert(name,filterWithData);
                });

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker for your problem. Please check:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SDa0LoUZt5D9zZEmAVt)

```
 $scope.refreshData = function (termObj) {
   $scope.gridOptions2.data = $scope.data;
    if (termObj.length > 2) {

        while (termObj) {
            var oSearchArray = termObj.split(' ');
            $scope.gridOptions2.data = $filter('filter')($scope.gridOptions2.data, oSearchArray[0], undefined);
            console.log($scope.gridOptions2.data)
            oSearchArray.shift();
            termObj = (oSearchArray.length !== 0) ? oSearchArray.join(' ') : '';
        }
    }
    else {
        $scope.gridOptions2.data = $scope.gridData;
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);
    }
    $scope.$apply();
};
```